# calling gdal_merge.py from c++ with arguments

Tags: python, c++, arguments, boost-python

I want to call the gdal_merge.py script from my c++ code and pass arguments to that call. When calling the script from the command line, you can do it like this:

```
gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata 0 -o [someOutputFile] [inputFiles]
```

However, I can't get the call working from my c++ code because I do not know how to pass the arguments to the main method of the python script. 
I've tried it like this:

```
// this is where the gdal_merge.py script is located
setenv("PYTHONPATH", "/usr/bin/", 1);

// Initialize Python.
Py_Initialize();

namespace python = boost::python;
try {
    python::object gdal_merge_modul = python::import("gdal_merge");

    std::string arguments = "-n 0 -a_nodata 0 -of GTiff -o";
    arguments = arguments.append(outputFile);
    arguments = arguments.append(inputFiles);
    arguments = arguments.append(outputFile).append(",").append(inputFiles);

    gdal_merge_modul.attr("main")(arguments);
}catch(const python::error_already_set&)
{
    PyErr_Print();
}
```

This throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 313, in main
    argv = gdal.GeneralCmdLineProcessor( argv )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 2959, in GeneralCmdLineProcessor
return _gdal.GeneralCmdLineProcessor(*args)
TypeError: not a sequence
```

I've also tried a char* array instead of the string:

```
const char* arguments[] = {"-n", "0", "-a_nodata", "0", "-of", "GTiff", "-o", outputFile.c_str(), inputFiles.c_str()};
```

But this throws the error:

```
No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: char const* [9]
```

How should I pass these arguments to make it work?

---

UPDATE:
Ok, I've got further using `boost::python::list`. Now, I am struggling with building the list correctly to make it work

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it:

```
python::list args;
args.append("-n"); args.append("0"); args.append("-a_nodata"); args.append("0"); args.append("-of"); args.append("GTiff");
args.append("-o"); args.append(outputFile);
for(std::string file : filePaths)
{
    args.append(file);
}
```